# Outputting Year of Entry Group alongside Month

Tags: entries, date

I have this piece of code which orders my entries by month, which is working great. I only have two issues which I can't work out. How would I display the year of the month beside the month title eg:

```
<h2>{{ month }} > {{ year }}</h2>
```

As the list could run over a number of years it would be good to distinguish this. The next part is I can't seem to convert the month from a number ie: 8 to the word ie. "august". When I filter it, it just returns "Jan".

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('featureArticles').find() %}
{% set allEntriesByMonth = allEntries|group('postDate.month') %}

{% for month, entriesInMonth in allEntriesByMonth %}

    <h2>{{ month }}</h2>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entriesInMonth %}
            <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close!

We've got an example of how to do this here: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-archive#grouping-by-year-and-then-month

The trick is to group by year first, then by month.  Using the 'F' token is how to [tell PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to display the name of the month.

Comment: Thanks Brad, this seems like it will do the trick. Can I still use the {{ year }} tag inside the month loop so it gives me August - 2014 as a title?

Comment: Yup... will still work fine there.  If that gets you what you want, mind marking this as the correct answer?